# create a maximum of 8 items per row(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am extremely new to python. i have googled but i haven't found what i need for hours.

i'm very confused on why my program is like this and would very much appreciate pointers. so this is my program:

```
number = int(input("Enter number: "))  
mylist = []  

if number > 1:
    for num in range(1,number + 1):  
        if num > 1:  
             for i in range(2,num): 
                  if (num % i) == 0:  
                      break                 
             else:  
                  mylist.append(str(num))
                  print(mylist)


else:
    print("no prime number")
```

so e.g if i insert 50 i wanted it to have an output of something like:

```
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19',
'23', '29', '31', '37', '41', '43', '47']
```

but instead what i got was this chaos

```
['2']
['2', '3']
['2', '3', '5']
['2', '3', '5', '7']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37', '41']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37', '41', '43']
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19', '23', '29', '31', '37', '41', '43', '47']
```

Comment: you print your list every time you `mylist.append(str(num))` . If you only want to print it once, print it at the end of your program.

Comment: @MT756 thanks man didn't know that was a problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can group them into sublists of 8 for the purpose of printing. Just make  your mylist as usual by appending the values then after you have processed all the values you can print sublists of 8

```py
number = int(input("Enter number: "))
mylist = []

if number > 1:
    for num in range(1,number + 1):
        if num > 1:
             for i in range(2,num):
                  if (num % i) == 0:
                      break
             else:
                  mylist.append(str(num))
    print(*[mylist[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(mylist), 8)], sep="\n")
else:
    print("no prime number")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13', '17', '19']
['23', '29', '31', '37', '41', '43', '47']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is indented incorrectly:

```
number = int(input("Enter number: "))  
mylist = []  

if number > 1:
    for num in range(1,number + 1):  
        if num > 1:  
             for i in range(2,num): 
                  if (num % i) == 0:  
                      break                 
             else:  
                  mylist.append(str(num))
    print(mylist)
else:
    print("no prime number")
```